# How to list all test cases using xcodebuild without running?

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

Using xcodebuild I can run a specific test or group of tests. But is there a way to list all tests without running them, using xcodebuild or any other tool that comes with xcode? Facebook's xctool can do this but I hope to not take dependency on third party tools.

Comment: you should be more clear what do you mean by "a way to list all tests without running them" ? do you mean xcodebuild test-without-build ?

Comment: test-without-build will run all tests. I just want a list of all test names, so that I can run them one by one with separate xcodebuild command lines.

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never - I also needed to do this and couldn't find a way using xcode, so I wrote a python script that parses the test files and gets the names of XCTest test functions:

```
import re
import os

all_tests = []
TEST_FILES = os.path.expanduser("~/git/ios-proj/Test")
test_case_pattern = re.compile(r"^\s*func\s(test\w*)\(\)[\s\w]*\{")
for test_file in os.listdir(TEST_FILES):
    all_tests += [test_case_pattern.match(line)[1] for line in
                 open(os.path.join(TEST_FILES, test_file), "r").readlines() if test_case_pattern.match(line)]
print(all_tests)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the test names by using "strings". it's not an xcode command, but is normally available on the mac. Run "strings" on the following file and grep whatever marks your tests. in my case, all tests start with "test_":

```
strings <Tests-Target>-Runner.app/PlugIns/<Tests-Target>.xctest/<Tests-Target>|grep "test_"
```

an easy way to find this file is by running:

```
grep -r <single test name> <derived data folder for your project>
```

Answer (score -5):

I cannot think of any way to sort automatically... but 
If you want to test one of the classes by one command So you can run your test one by one through this command :

> xcodebuild test -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=11.1'  '-only-testing:APPNAME-TESTTARGET/NAMEOFTHECLASS'

also you can see your list of targets, builds configurations, and schemes by using this command :

```
 xcodebuild -list
```

Comment: But before that I need to find all the test cases and methods available...

Comment: you have to find the classes manually, the only thing you can do is just see the list of targets, build configurations, and schemas by using this command  : xcodebuild -list

Comment: There is actually a way to do it using Facebook's xctool. But it's doing something hacky and new xcode version can break it. I need it in CI so I hope there is a tool supported by Apple.

Comment: what you can do with datebook school ? tell me the command If there is anything in facebook school there should be a away doing it with Xcode command line tool.

Comment: xctool doesn't just run some xcode tool directly. It loads the bundle and injects some code into it. That's why I call it "hacky".

Comment: Im sure that xcode command line tool doesn't have anything to list your test cases and methods, you should defiantly use some third parties and frameworks to do that.

Comment: btw, you can write your own scripts which will run specific test classes and methods and save it on your CI, So you don't need to find the classes and methods each time.

Comment: Maryam, the OP wants to generate this list dynamically without resorting to maintaining a list or a third party tool.